# New Year Resolutions

Tags: buddha-nature

What are some resolution that we can made in order to make the upcoming year more peaceful ,fruitful. Resolutions which may bring some major changes in our life?

Comment: This question does not appear to be a good fit for StackExchange, as it will elicit only opinions.

Comment: There is no correct answer to this poorly framed question.  Any possible answer is arbitrary and capricious.  Every respondent is required to elevate their own premise above that of the questioner in order to establish sufficient framework to reach a mature conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In school, teachers was asking students their resolutions, they can be not to lie, getting high score and so on.
But after some days or times gone no one seem aware of resolutions they had made at start of new year. Seldom of them aware of it; so if I've made resolution as not to lie, first thing I need to remind myself about it for practically achieve it. Need to mind control to not to lie. And so you asking for making year peaceful and happy then you can set it as practicing better than before and so many as you wishing. Meditation is there also you can made resolution of it and you'll have peaceful and bright year, not even year but life.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late in answering this, but not too late. IMHO.. to be in the timeless present is a good New Year’s Resolution that will open a whole new world anyone who would take this challenge. We are still at a threshold right now, as it is just one month into the dawn of 2017 after another year has come to an end.  Put into practice what you know of Dhamma right now. The one all important Pali word is ‘APPAMADA’.  You will not postpone any acts or decisions for a ‘tomorrow’. Life is in the today – life is here and now. For many,  this Dhamma Path has created new possibilities, that only in living in the present we can learn to live this truth.

Only if we develop two important attitudes that strengthen skillful desires: a sense of dismay (samvega) over the universality of suffering, and an attitude of heedfulness (appamada) to avoid being duped by types of desires that come our way, that we will have a sense of urgency towards the practice of Dhamma.

The ‘Ehipassico’ & “Opanaiko’ qualities of the Dhamma invites you to come and see it for yourself.  But would you – I mean in the truest sense of the meaning?  If such thinking could help you to have less attachment to the senses – the eyes / seeing, the ears / hearing, the nose / smell, the tongue / taste, the touch and the thoughts – you will find a much more beautiful heavenly world out there that you have never explored.

In the not too distant future, we are going to face old age, when only with difficulty that one could maintain the body – it is just as maintaining a dilapidated old cart. Your body can be at ease. Even if you will feel the pain, you will not suffer when you enter upon and dwell in the minds realm.

A fact of life that almost every one of us deny, is that life is suffering. If you see this truth, understand it, accept it and go beyond it, you will find a peace of mind and happiness as you have never experienced before. If you truly understand this fact of life that is common to every living being, understand the core reason for it, and detach yourself from clinging to all such, then you will experience true peace.  I wish you a Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhism Dhamma should be experienced here and now. In order to do that you have to practice [Vipassanā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81). Hence a fruitful resolution would be that you pratice 1 hour in the morning and evening and to do at least one retreat for the year.